# INSERT simple Array with dynamic indexes to Php-Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, for-loop

how y can store in my BD Mysql this array:

```
Array ( [3] => 23 [9] => 54 )
```

Structure of Bd Table is:

```
ID_PROD |  QUANT
----------------------
3          23     
9          54
```

I tried with this code, but without results, my problem are the INDEXEs of array

```
$arr1 = $_GET['sols']; 

$sql = array(); 
foreach( $arr1 as $row ) {
$sql[] =   '('.$row['???????'].','.$row['??????????'].')';
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO sales (ID_PROD,QUANT) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: ^^^^as true as it is, its getting a little tedious for regular S.O users to see it 10+ times a day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually populate your query with the data from the array.

```
$arr1 = $_GET['sols']; 

$sql = array(); 
foreach( $arr1 as $key => $row ) {
$sql[] =   '(' . $key . ',' . $row.')';
}
mysql_query('INSERT INTO sales (ID_PROD,QUANT) VALUES '.implode(',', $sql));
```

Also, please rework your code to not use `mysql_query`. Use the better PDO or mysqli frameworks (or something similar).